# Show/hide various elements in ngFor Angular

Tags: json, angular, html-table, json-server

I have a table, which displays data in ngFor. When I delete an element, I want to hide it.
I figured I have to do a variable in my record component `hide:boolean` which is false by default, but when I click od delete button, it changes to true. I don't know how to "catch" this variable in my table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Id
      </th>
      <th> 
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Surname
      </th>
      <th>
        Actions
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr sl-record *ngFor="let recordElement of records" [record]="recordElement" [hidden]="recordElement.hide"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my record component:

```
<td>{{record.id}}</td>
<td>{{record.name}}</td>
<td>{{record.surname}}</td>
<td>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="Actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeRecord(record.id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove
    </button>
  </div>
</td>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have my data in json file, connected by json-server. I delete record with `http.delete()` function. It gets deleted from my file, but the table does not reload by itself.

record component, removeRecod function:

```
removeRecord(id) {
    var url = this.data_url + "/" + id;
    this.http.delete(url).subscribe();
    this.hide = true;
  }
```

Comment: I haven't touched angular in awhile but this sounds like something that can be solved with `apply()`

Comment: @Huangism any hint how can I use this `apply()`? I can't find any documentation about it...

Comment: What does your removeRecord(record.id)-method look like? Do you set the hide-field of your object to true?

Comment: @DiabolicWords updated my post :)

Comment: You're just deleting the record on the server. You'll need to reassign `records` to the result of your delete call I assume.

Comment: @Olga looking at your code now it's not an apply issue, your `this.hide` I don't think that's the same variable as the one in the ngFor. Again, I havent touched it in a long time but that does not look right. The hide you need is the `record.hide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two basic options here:

1. pass in the entire record object to the delete function and switch "hide" to true

   ```
   removeRecord(record) {
      record.hide = true;
      let id = record.id;
      // do whatever to delete on server
   }
   ```
2. (better) remove the record from the list itself rather than trying to hide it.

   ```
   removeRecord(id) {
      //do whatever to delete the record on server

      let recordIndex = this.records.findIndex(r => r.id === id);
      this.records = this.records.splice(recordIndex, 1);
   }
   ```

Comment: I did an event emitter from record to table component, but you had a good idea with `splice`, which I forgot existed :) So, I made it in other way than you suggested, but you were my inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

You only have the id of your object. Do it this way:

```
 removeRecord(id: number){
    var url = this.data_url + "/" + id;
    this.http.delete(url).subscribe();

    this.records.forEach(element => {
        if(element.id === id){
          element.hide = true;
        }
    });
 }
```